# Image starts rotating from starting position after one click

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image

I have an image which is rotated by 36°. 
I used setFillAfter() and setFillEnabled(). It's saving the position but if I rotate it again it is starting from the original position. I want it to start from the position it was after rotation.

```
Animation animation = new Animation (0,36, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
animation.setDuration(3000);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.setFillAfter(true);

myImage.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass current angle of imageview  in **Animation** Constructor instead of 0 everytime. Try below code:

```
        int rotationAngle=36;/*angle by which you want to rotate image*/
        int mCurrRotation = 0;  /*current angle of image*/

        buttonRotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float fromRotation = mCurrRotation;
            float toRotation = mCurrRotation += rotationAngle;

            Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(
                    fromRotation,
                    toRotation,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);


            animation.setDuration(3000);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            myImage.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For that after performing rotation set x y coordinate of image to new position where it got rotated ...